# How to mock a service in acceptance test in Loopback 4

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, loopback4

I am writing some tests in Loopback 4 and I need to mock / stub a service, I mean I need to replace it in bindings by a stub one. But I can't find how to do this.

I want to write tests such as this one :

```
it(`should work if a user was found for the token in 'authorization' header`, async () => {
  await client
    .get('/mock')
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer a-good-token')
    .expect(200);
});
```

For this I have to start an application before each test suite in `before` method.
I boot my application then I try to change the binding for my service :

```
before('setupApplication', async () => {
  app = new MyApplication();
  await app.boot();
  app.bind('services.WebAuthService').to(MockWebAuthService); // to replace with the mocked one
  app.controller(MockController);
  await app.start();
}
```

I tried different ways to write my MockWebAuthService :

- With Sinon stub :

```
const utilisateur = sinon.createStubInstance(Utilisateur);
utilisateur.uId = 123456;
const verifyCredentialsStub = sinon.stub().resolves(undefined);
verifyCredentialsStub
  .withArgs({token: 'a-good-token'})
  .resolves(utilisateur);
const MockWebAuthService: WebAuthService = sinon.createStubInstance(
  WebAuthService,
  {
    verifyCredentials: verifyCredentialsStub,
    convertToUserProfile: sinon.stub(),
  },
);
```

- Or with a new class :

```
class MockWebAuthService implements UserService<Utilisateur, Credentials> {

  async verifyCredentials(credentials: Credentials): Promise<Utilisateur> {
    const utilisateur = sinon.createStubInstance(Utilisateur);
    utilisateur.uId = 123456;
    if (credentials.token === 'a-good-token') {
      return utilisateur;
    } else {
      throw new Error('invalid token');
    }
  }

  convertToUserProfile(utilisateur: Utilisateur): UserProfile {
    return {} as UserProfile;
  }
}
```

But none of these works. The `WebAuthService` that is injected in my components is still the one from `src/services`, not the mocked one.

Any idea how I should do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem. I was wrong in the way I binded the stub service.

It works this way :

```
app.getBinding('services.WebAuthService').to(MockWebAuthService);
```